# Most significant bit

Tags: c#, hardware, bit

I haven't dealt with programming against hardware devices in a long while and have forgotten pretty much all the basics.

I have a spec of what I should send in a byte and each bit is defined from the most significant bit (bit7) to the least significant (bit 0).  How do i build this byte?  From MSB to LSB, or vice versa?

Comment: When you say "build" what do you mean? - it seems like you have all the information you need.

Comment: just try... if it doesn't work, reverse order. Most common is to have bit 0 as the lsb

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If these bits are being 'packeted' (which they usually are), then the order of bits is the native order, 0 being the LSB, and 7 being the MSB. Bits are not usually sent one-by-one, but as bytes (usually more than one byte...).

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_significant_bit), bit ordering can sometimes be from 7->0, but this is probably the rare case.

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to write the whole byte at the same time, i.e. do a parallel transfer as opposed to a serial, the order of the bits doesn't matter.

If the transfer *is* serial, then you must find out which order the device expects the bits in, it's impossible to tell from the outside.

To just assemble a byte from eight bits, just use bitwise-OR to "add" bits, one at a time:

```
byte value = 0;

value |= (1 << n);  // 'n' is the index, with 0 as the LSB, of the bit to set.
```

Answer (score 1):

If the spec says MSB, then build it MSB. Otherwise if the spec says LSB, then build it LSB. Otherwise, ask for more information.

Comment: The spec says nothing.  In some places the bits are listed from 0 to 7, in other places from 7 to 0.  What is the most common way?

Comment: According to this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_significant_bit both ways exist. From my experience, 0 is the LSB.